# picking out rows and columns in matrix

Tags: python, matrix, row

In Python, I have defined my matrix the following way

```
A = [[1, 4, 5, 12], 
    [-5, 8, 9, 0],
    [-6, 7, 11, 19],
    [-2, 7, 4, 23]]
```

and wanted to try printing out the individual columns and rows by the following
`print(A[2][:])` and `print(A[:][2])` for the 3rd row and 3rd column, respectively.

To my surprise, they both printed the 3rd row.

For the purpose of learning, I am not using Numpy or any math packages.

Not sure why `print(A[2][:])` and `print(A[:][2])` result in the same output

Comment: `A[:][2]` means "take the entirety of `A`, then get the third row", and `A[2][:]` means "take the third row of `A`, then take the entirety of that row".

Comment: Try this to see if you can get what you want -  `for col in zip(*A): print(col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to follow the same principles of accessing various elements in lists. Namely, by calling `A[2]` for example, you are calling the entire data in the 3rd element (which in this case is its own list). By further stating `A[2][:]` you are calling all elements within the 3rd list. The same logic is applied to the `A[:][2]` call - namely, all the information is called within your A list and then you further stipulate that you want the 3rd element shown - this is namely the 3rd 'sublist' so to say.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a column, you need to manually loop throw all rows and extract the elements, e.g., with a list comprehension:

```py
third_column = [row[2] for row in A]
```